# Collect multiple RequireJS dependencies

Tags: javascript, requirejs

There's a set of JS modules representing similar OOP Classes: think of e.g. different types of backend tasks (`SendEmailTask`, `WriteToDbTask`, `WriteToDiskTask`), or different actions on a drawing canvas (`DrawArc`, `DrawLine`, `DrawBezier`). Those are just examples.

Each of those is a single JS file, with its own `define`, and they're all located in a common directory. In a client module that depends on all of those, the dependency list and argument list have to include each one of those separately, e.g. something like:

```js
define([
  'tasks/sendEmailTask', 'tasks/writeToDbTask', 'tasks/writeToDiskTask', ...
  ], function (SendEmailTask, WriteToDbTask, WriteToDiskTask, ...) { 
    /* ... */ 
    /* ... new SendEmailTask(); */ 
    /* ... new WriteToDbTask(); */ 
    /* ... new WriteToDiskTask(); */ 
  });
```

and they both must be updated everytime a new module is added to the set, e.g. `MakeCoffeeTask`, which seems to me as a BadThing™.

Is there a way to avoid those last issues? I was thinking of a couple of possible ways, but I don't know how to make them work:

1. Create a kind of *namespace* module. Each of those sub-modules depends on the namespace one and adds its definition to it. But than if the client too depends only on the namespace, how do you ensure that client gets loaded *after* all sub-modules?
2. Express both dependencies and arguments with some kind of wildcard, like `'tasks/*'` for dependency and *< no idea >* for arguments.

Comment: https://github.com/component/guide was created to solve it

Comment: I'm sorry but I did not get it. AFAIK Component.io is a collection of JS libraries/tools. And I read that *guide* is a guide to that. How can this help me in finding a solution? Thanks

Comment: ```component``` is JavaScript framework for managing dependencies and their automatic update. Supports multiple module frameworks. If you'd use it your problems would go away, see https://github.com/component/guide/blob/master/component/vs.md (and the FAQ). I'm sorry if I misunderstood what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find any other solution. This is what I came up with in the meantime... it is just an improvement over current situation, but I don't think it solves the posed issues.

```js
// in tasks/taskNamespace.js or in any client code

define (function(require) {

  var _taskArray = [
    require('tasks/sendEmailTask'),
    require('tasks/writeToDbTask'),
    require('tasks/writeToDiskTask'),
    /* ... , */
  ];

  var TaskNamespace = {};

  _taskArray.forEach(function (taskClass) {
    TaskNamespace[taskClass.name] = taskClass;
  });

  return TaskNamespace;

});
```

It takes advantage of [RequireJS Sugar](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar) syntax and of [JS Function.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) coming new feature, proposed in ES6.

What's the end result? You still have to manually add each *Class* to a list, but it's only **one** list instead of **two**. WHOA

Answer (score 0):

You can make a different module for each section. For example: 'tasks/main'
in the Task main you can include all the files you need. and in the task main, all the function of task will be assigned. and you call high level functions. Take look :

```
define(['tasks/main'], function(task){

   task.add('Project Status meeting');
   task.SendEmailNotification('tAll');
```

});

in the task/main.js :

```
define(['tasks/sendEmailTask', 'tasks/writeToDbTask', 'tasks/writeToDiskTask',], function(sendEmailTask, writeToDbTask, writeToDiskTask){
  var task = {
        add = function(taskObj){
             // write your code using writeToDbTask, writeToDiskTask 
        }, 
        SendEmailNotification =  function(whom){
               // write your code using sendEmailTask, writeToDbTask, writeToDiskTask    
        };

   return task;           

});
```

does it help you ?

Comment: Thanks for your input: this is basically the current situation. As you can see, dependency list and argument list in `main.js` must be updated everytime. I was looking for a way to not explicitly state those two lists.

Comment: My input was, make one file kind of like a library. Like jQuery.animate() --> task.doThis() Or task.UpadteText(). once you have included all the task stuff in the task library you dont have to touch anything in that file.